# How to run hp.x command in Quantum ESPRESSO 6.8?

Tags: quantum-espresso, hubbard-model

How to run `hp.x` command in QuantumEspresso v6.8? It is saying `command not found`.

After doing `make hp`, it is saying `command not found`.

Comment: Did you compiled *hp* successfully?

Answer (score 4):

Executables are soft-linked in `./bin` folder of the parent directory. If you did not compile, please follow these [steps](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/user_guide/node13.html).

```
make hp
cd bin
```

After that, run the command,

```
./hp.x
```

If you are accessing the executable from QE input file folder, then you have to specify the whole path of the executable

```
/path-to-qe-folder/bin/hp.x
```

The best practice is to `export` the [path variables](https://linuxhint.com/export-a-path-in-bashrc/) into the `~/.bashrc` or similar file, so that it can be accessible anywhere.

P.S. I presume you are using some flavor of linux OS or atleast compatible linux shell in windows.

Comment: You are assuming that the user has `.` on his/her path, which is often considered to be not very good practice and so might not be the case. Probably better is `./hp.x`

Comment: @IanBush Yeah, you are right. Thankx, I'll edit it.